# Replace values with string mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a VARCHAR column in which some values end with the digit '5'. These 
values may be of different lengths. I want to replace all such values
with the string 'UTR-5'. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the fastest solution, but:

```
update myTable set value = 'UTR-5' where value like '%5'
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't think of it myself!